# Python to output record associated with median value of a tuple list, determined by numpy

Tags: python, numpy, median

I'm using `numpy` to find the median value from a list of tuples like this:

```
print(np.median( [x[1] for x in pairs]) )
```

The `Pairs` themselves come from the [collections.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), and individually they look like this:

```
Pair(hash=u'0x034c9e7f28f136188ebb2a2630c26183b3df90c387490159b411cf7326764341', gas=21000)
Pair(hash=u'0xffda7269775dcd710565c5e0289a2254c195e006f34cafc80c4a3c89f479606e', gas=1000000)
Pair(hash=u'0x90ca439b7daa648fafee829d145adefa1dc17c064f43db77f573da873b641f19', gas=90000)
Pair(hash=u'0x7cba9f140ab0b3ec360e0a55c06f75b51c83b2e97662736523c26259a730007f', gas=40000)
Pair(hash=u'0x92dedff7dab405220c473aefd12e2e41d260d2dff7816c26005f78d92254aba2', gas=21000)
```

This is the method where I determine the median:

```
pairs = list(_as_pairs(dict_hash_gas))
# pprint.pprint(pairs)
if pairs:
    # Avoid a ValueError from min() and max() if the list is empty.
    print(min(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.gas))
    print(max(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.gas))
    print(np.median( [x[1] for x in pairs]) )
```

Here is how the structure is created:

```
def _as_pairs(pairs):
    for pair in pairs:
        # TODO:  Verify the dict conatains exactly one item?
        for k, v in pair.items():
            # Should the `key` string also be an integer?
            #yield Pair(key=int(k, base=16), value=int(v))
            yield Pair(hash=k, gas=int(v))
```

The full script can be sound [here](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/c7939fc2ce58730d972639040b543654).

At the moment the output is like this:

```
Pair(hash=u'0xf4f034e23b4118cb4aa4e9d077f0f28d675e25e9dc2650225f32ac33e04c93aa', gas=21000)
Pair(hash=u'0x92de9056a6357752a46dff1d6ff274d204d450bbd6c51cefe757f199af105cb4', gas=4712388)
90000.0
```

The question is, how could I output the entire record, the entire `Pair`, associated with the median value, as opposed to just the median value itself?

Comment: At first I thought you could replace `print(np.median( [x[1] for x in pairs]) )` by `print(np.median((pair.gas, pair) for pair in pairs)[1])`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What should happen if the median value is not in the data?

Comment: examine the two competing potential values and choose one of them at random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of median Pair, but it needs one more lines:

1) If you allways have `len(pairs)%2 == 1`, the median is unique and belongs to the pairs:

```
gases = np.array([pair.gas for pair in pairs])
medianGasIndex = np.where( gases == np.median(gases) )[0][0]
print(pairs[medianGasIndex])
```

2) If you may have `len(pairs)%2 == 0`, then you have to choose:

2.1) Either you want the median Pair that is the nearest value of the real median value (i.e. the 50 percentile, that is not contained in the dataset)

```
medianGasIndex = np.where( gases == np.percentile(gases,50,interpolation='nearest') )[0][0]
```

2.2) or you want both the right and left median values

```
leftMedianGasIndex = np.where( gases == np.percentile(gases,50,interpolation='lower') )[0][0]
rightMedianGasIndex = np.where( gases == np.percentile(gases,50,interpolation='higher') )[0][0]
```

It works with this [minimal working example](https://pastebin.com/jZKQm0um), just edit the way to get the median value acording to your needs.

Comment: This will fail if the result of `np.median()` is not contained in the `pairs`, e.g. if include an additional `Pair(hash=u'0x7cba9f140agfsdsg60e0a55c06f75b51c83b2e97662736523c26259a730007f', gas=500)` the above code will not work.

Comment: Thanks @norok2, I edited my answer to solve the problem you raised.

Answer (score 1):

The question is ill-posed, because there is no value that is really associated to the median: it could happen that the `median` value is not present in the original array, e.g. `np.median([0, 1])` equals `0.5`.

Instead, what you could do is to find the value of `pairs` closest to the median, using `np.argmin()`, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(10, 20)
median_val = np.median(arr)
print(median_val)
# output: 14.5

i = np.argmin(np.abs(arr - median_val))
print(i)
# output: 4
print(arr[i])
# output: 14
```

For your code, this might be something like:

```
gases_arr = np.array([pair.gas for pair in pairs])
median_val = np.median(gases_arr)
i = np.argmin(np.abs(gases_arr - median_gases))
print(i, pairs[i])
```

unless, of course, you want the value to be printed only if the `median` is actually present in the array, in which case you either check `pairs[i] == median_val` or you use `where` as outlined in some other answer.